# What is the max number of permissions I can assign to a custom role on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

Say an organization has custom IAM roles – service accounts are assigned any number of roles. Is there a max number of permissions per custom role that can be assigned?

Comment: There is no absolute number of permissions per role. The limit is **Total size of the title, description, and permission names** which is 64 KB.

Comment: Provide as an answer with citation and I'll accept as the answer? @JohnHanley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no absolute number of permissions per role. The limit is ***Total size of the title, description, and permission names*** which is 64 KB.

[IAM Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas#limits)

Answer (score 2):

Currently based on the [IAM limits](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas#limits), the limit of custom roles for an organization is 300

The limit for a single custom role is actually not by number of permissions, but by serialized role size in byte. Currently the limit is 64KB. And each permission has slightly different serialized size, so you will expect to see the number of permission limit defer as the role has different permissions.

Comment: Although statement is correct I do not believe that answers poster's question. He is asking for max number of permission with one custom role.

Comment: correct @danyL -> this does not answer my Q unfortunately.